# Moving a file in terminal using mv

Tags: unix, terminal, mv

I have a simple python file simple_events.py that was mistakenly saved outside of my python_practice directory. I am trying to move it back into this directory but I get an error when try.

command:

```
mv simple_events.py/python_practice
```

second command:

```
mv simple_events.py/Users/One-Life.Grind./python_practice
```

error:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

If someone could tell me why this isn't working and how to correct it, it would me much appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a space between source and target.

Comment: `mv simple_events.py /Users/One-Life.Grind./python_practice`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mv -u simple_events.py/python_practice
```

The usage of "-u" means that an existing file will be overwritten if the source file is newer than the file already in place. I would just cp the file

```
cp -rp /source.file /destination.file
```

then remove the source by

```
sudo rm source.file
```

EDIT:: The "-rp" will recursively copy all folders within a folder, and their respective permissions to the new location.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to move everything where it needed to be.

Comment: Please tick the "answered" checkbox so that others know this solution was of use. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a dot at the end

```
mv simple_events.py/Users/One-Life.Grind./python_practice .
```